# Creating “distance to” raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, proximity, rasterization

I imagine there’s a proper term for what I’m trying to do but, if so, I do not know it.

I have a map of populated areas, as polygons. I can rasterise that, but what interests me isn’t the effect of the populated area, but distance to the nearest populated area.

Is there a way to create a raster which has a 0 for cells with populated areas in it, 1 for those adjacent to populated areas, 2 for those at least one cell away from a populated area, etc using QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Proximity (raster distance)](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html#proximity-raster-distance) processing tool:

> Generates a raster proximity map indicating the distance from the center of each pixel to the center of the nearest pixel identified as a target pixel.